# How can I organize my data flow to process a good program solution?

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices, development-process, coding-standards

My main problem when trying to form a program is that while I have the tools at my disposal, I am too disorganized to properly use them to solve my problems.  Often my process is simply trial and error until the program works.

I am looking to see what others use to organize the process of writing programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognizing that there's a better way than trial & error is the first step.

I usually start with paper & pencil.  I get a rough sense of what the client's asking for and sketch out the User Experience.  I need to know what the user needs to see, what they need to do, etc.  For larger projects, this would evolve into Requirements docs, Functional specifications, a Vision, etc.  I'd also identify user stories on a per-Role basis.

My next step is to look at where the data comes from, how I'm going to store it, what manipulations (if any) I need to do on it, etc.  This includes both in-memory storage and database (not every program requires a database).  [Data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) are your friend.  Picking the right data organization will make the difference between a program that's a joy to use & one that's barely tolerable.

Program organization comes next - what objects do I have, how do they communicate, how do I segregate functionality so I separate stuff that changes from stuff that doesn't, how do I keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), etc.

There are some canned designs (such as [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) that can be useful.  The trick is knowing when the designs are appropriate and when they aren't so you don't suffer from [hammer syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

Right before I start coding I take a final look at my plan and look for things to remove.  There's a term for this -- "[YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI)".  Also, remember - you don't have to fix any features you leave out.

At this point I have the start of a plan - when I sit down at the keyboard I have an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

You might also want to read up on [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) - it's a very good technique, but not by itself an answer to your question.

Comment: Excellent information.  I now have a direction to start moving from hobbyist to professional.  I appreciate your time and input.